# Not able to Write to csv File using Rstudio

Tags: r, file, csv, rstudio

using wite.csv function i'm not able to write to a csv fie

```
write.csv(data.frame(Actual,Predicted), file="SampleData.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

I expected a SampleData.csv file in my folder but i am getting this error

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'SampleData.csv': No such file or directory
```

I tried to change the directory ,but still i'm getting same error.

Comment: It looks like R did not have write permission to the directory that you are trying to write the file.

Comment: How did you try to change the directory? What directory are you trying to write to exactly?

Comment: @cory Thanks , Window defender's ransomware protection was block R to write to files.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried to change the directory in Rstudio by going to   Session-> Set working directory . I changes to source file location and to documents . But now my problem is solved ,Window defender's ransomware protection was block R to write to files.